# Getting the true value of an object from a fetched source in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm getting a list of countries by fetching data from an external API in `VueX`. I then use a mutation to store these list of countries to a state.

So in effect, I'm storing the countries in a variable that I refer to as `this.$state.getters.countryList` from a component. Now I need to compare if a variable exists in that list.

So I use this method:
`this.$store.getters.countryList.indexOf('usa')`.

I know for a fact that `'usa'` exists in that list, but I always get `-1` as a result.

I then tried to debug the value of `this.$state.getters.countryList` by using `console.log(this.$state.getters.countryList)` and I get `[__ob__: Observer]` as the result in the console.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
  mounted() {
    if (this.$store.getters.countryList.indexOf('usa')) {
       //Do something
      }
  }
```

How can I get the actual value of `this.$state.getters.countryList` and use that in conjunction with `indexOf()` to perform a check to do something else?

Comment: When your `mounted` hook runs, there probably isn't any data in `countryList`. You need to run your checks at the appropriate time, after the data is fetched from the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since fetching data from external API is an `async` operation, the data you are trying to access might not be available at the time when you need it as mentioned by @Phil.

For that reason you could set a watcher to run your set of instructions once the `fetch` operation is completed and `countryList` is loaded:

In `store.js`, let's say you got your `countryList` that is set to `null` in your store initially:

```
export const state = () => ({
 countryList: null
})
```

Then in your `mounted()` hook you would set a watcher:

```
mounted() {
 this.$store.watch(
  state => state.countryList,
  (value) => {
   if (value) { 
     //instruction once countryList is loaded 
   }
  }
 )
}
```